# How do I get Docker to see files in the mount path in WSL?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

With my Ubuntu bash terminal open, `${PWD}` shows `/mnt/c/Projects/Web/MySite`

Neither of these two host paths will list the contents in the directory:

`docker run -it --volume ${PWD}:/app my-image ls`

`docker run -it --volume /mnt/c/Projects/Web/MySite:/app my-image ls`

**However, these work just fine:**

`docker run -it --volume c:/Projects/Web/MySite:/app my-image ls`

`docker run -it --volume /c/Projects/Web/MySite:/app my-image ls`

Rather than having to type out the full Windows host path, I would like to be able to just use `${PWD}` or something equivalent.

So I have two questions:

1. Can I somehow get Docker to see the contents in `/mnt/c/` via WSL, or...
2. Is there something analogous to `${PWD}` that will output `/c/Projects/Web/MySite` rather than `/mnt/c/Projects/Web/MySite` so that I don't have to type it out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Bind Mounts in WSL do not show files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51627619/docker-bind-mounts-in-wsl-do-not-show-files)

Comment: You should alway start with google, rather than SO. This is a well known issue and it's well documented both in SO and on external sites: https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly   and   https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl-tech-preview/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
docker run -v / host_mnt / c / Projects / Web / MySite
```

In container the folder */ mnt* is read as */ host_mnt*

This solution works for me!

Answer (score -1):

This is a [known problem for Windows](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/1203).
I don't really have an alternate solution.

Comment: Hey, your answer was flagged. It's a comment, not an answer.